# How can I start the numbering of my appendices by "B" (instead of "A")?

Tags: numbering, appendices

Let us consider the following example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.50in,bottom=.50in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,amsthm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\leftmark } 
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape Basic Algebraic Topology and its Applications}   


\newtheoremstyle{myplain}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')


\theoremstyle{myplain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\theoremstyle{proposition}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}


\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}% name
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')


\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
 \newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark}

 \newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
 \newtheorem*{cor*}{Corollary}


 \begin{document}
 \setcounter{page}{0}\mbox{}\newpage
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \def\chapternum{2}
 \setcounter{chapter}{1}
 \chapter{}
  This is my second chapter.
 \section{Section}
 \begin{thm}
  First Theorem.
 \end{thm}

 \appendix
 \chapter{Chapter in appendix}
 Text here

 \section{Section}
 \begin{defn}
  Definition
 \end{defn}


 \end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]

[image]

But I would like to produce the following :

[image]

[image]

That is I want to get the appendix number as in my choice.

Is there any  command like `\setcounter` (already I have used) that will change appendix number/name?

I have faced another problem : when I compile this program, I get the following warning:

> \headheight is too small (12.0pt): make it at least 14.49998pt'.

But whenever I put '14.49998pt' also shows a warning:

> 'Unused global option(s):[14pt]'.

Can anyone tell me how can I fix these problems?

Comment: To get the numbering you want (i.e. skip "Appendix A"), simply insert `\addtocounter{chapter}{1}` right after `\appendix`. You get a warning about `\headheight` being too small because your top margin and hence the height of your header is too small to contain the header (which you define using `\fancyhead`); this problem becomes obvious if you pass the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package. To get rid of that warning, you can pass an additional option to the `geometry` package: `headheight=14.5pt`.

Comment: although it is rather strange to have "appendix b" and no "appendix a", you can reset the number of the appendix by inserting `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` immediately after the `\appendix` command.  (`\appendix` resets the `chapter` counter to 0, and the next `\chapter` command steps the counter by 1, giving "a".)

Comment: My problems are solved by your tips.

Comment: @Jubobs I think you should turn this comment into an answer. :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1**: The `\appendix` command resets the chapter counter to zero--and sets the numbering style of subsequent chapters (which are really appendices) to `\Alph`. Therefore, if you want to skip "A" in the numbering of your appendices, simply increment the chapter counter by inserting `\stepcounter{chapter}` right after `\appendix`.

**Problem 2**: If not set explicitly, the length `\headheight` is determined by the value of the top margin, which you set to a relatively small length (`.5in`). LaTeX complains by issuing the warning

> \headheight is too small (12.0pt): make it at least 14.49998pt'.

because your `\headheight` is a bit too small to contain the header you defined with `\fancyhead`. The `showframe` option of the `geometry` package is helpful in identifying this kind of problems.

To get rid of that warning, you can manually set the value of length `\headheight` to an acceptable value. In your case, passing the option `headheight=14.5pt` to the `geometry` package solves the problem.